# Проблема с кодировкой при взаимодействии клиента с сервером

Tags: java, кодировка, протоколы

имеется следующий байтовый протокол:

```
// [0] - protocol type
// [1...4] - packet number
// [5...512] - email(254 symbols in UTF-8)
// [513...514] - email length
// [515...578] - password(32 symbols in UTF-8)
// [579] - password length
```

Код отправки пакета из клиента, написанного на С++(cтруктура пакуется правильно, все байты приходят в правильном порядке):

```
...

const std::wstring email = L"player@gmail.com";
const std::wstring password = L"difficult_password";

std::unique_ptr<Protocol::LoginPacket> packetToServer = std::make_unique<Protocol::LoginPacket>();
packetToServer->setPacketNumber(mPacketNumber++);
packetToServer->setEmailSize((std::int16_t) email.size());
packetToServer->setPasswordSize((std::int8_t) password.size());
packetToServer->setEmail(email.data());
packetToServer->setPassword(password.data());
mConnection.sendBuffer(packetToServer->toBuffer(), sizeof(Protocol::LoginPacket));

...
```

Код получения пакета на сервер, написанного на Java(за пример возьмем извлечение из буфера email):

```
...

private final static byte POSITION_EMAIL = 5; // index
private final static short SIZE_EMAIL = 254 * Primitives.CHAR_SIZE; // bytes
private final static short POSITION_OF_SIZE_EMAIL = 513; // index
private final static byte SIZE_OF_EMAIL_SIZE = Primitives.SHORT_SIZE; // bytes

...

public String getEmail(){
    return new String(buffer, POSITION_EMAIL, ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer, POSITION_OF_SIZE_EMAIL, SIZE_OF_EMAIL_SIZE).getShort() * Primitives.CHAR_SIZE);
}

...
```

Если вывести email в консоль на сервере, то выводится все отлично player@gmail.com, но стоить применить следующее:

```
if ("player@gmail.com".equals(protocol.getPassword())) {
   ...
}
```

То я получаю результат false, может кто-нибудь подскажет где я просчитался или где я чт-то не понимаю, так как уже второй день бьюсь над этой проблемой и все безуспешно... Уже и пробовал в разные кодировки переводить, но все безуспешно.

Comment: Во-первых, нужно убедиться, что при компиляции java-кода использовалась кодировка utf-8. Во-вторых, при создании строки явно указывать кодировку utf-8.

Comment: Проверено, только как не странно "player@gmail.com" возвращает 16 байт, т.е. 1 символ = 1 байту, а если добавить к примеру русский символ вмето одного английского "playeр@gmail.com", то вернет 17 байт. Это если UTF-8, а если указать UTF-16 то в первом случае будет 32 байта а во втором 34 байта...

Comment: Всё логично. В utf-8 символы не входящие в диапазон ascii кодируются последовательностями.

Comment: должно быть `"player@gmail.com".equals(protocol.getEmail())`?

Comment: Ошибка при задании вопроса, в коде все корректно

Comment: выведите рядом `Arrays.toString( protocol.getEmail().toCharArray() )` и `Arrays.toString( "player@gmail.com".toCharArray() )`. Чему у вас в java равен `Primitives.CHAR_SIZE`?